# How to check which checkbox is ticked?

Tags: php, html

I am currently creating a php web application. In one of my pages ("**pushnotification.php**") I am displaying a table that loads some information from mysql database and display them on the page. The table loads the Clients(primary key), name and surname in the table. I have also added another column in the table called Receive Message which consists of checkboxes. The table in the page looks like this:

[image]

The source code that creates the table is the following:

```
function user_clients_table() {

   $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root",'');
   if(!$con){

   die("Cannot Connect" . mysql_error());

   }
    mysql_select_db("client_app",$con);
    $get_user_clients = "SELECT `ID`,`Name`,`SurName` FROM `clients`  ";
    $clients = mysql_query($get_user_clients,$con);

   echo "<table  border=2>
   <tr>   
   <th>Client</th>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>SurName</th>
   <th>Receive Message</th>
   </tr>";
   while($record = mysql_fetch_array($clients)){
    echo "<form action=pushnotification.php method=post>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$record['ID']." </td>";
    echo "<td>".$record['Name']." </td>";
    echo "<td>".$record['SurName']." </td>";
    echo "<td>"."<input type=checkbox name=checkbox[".$record['ID']."] </td>";   
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";
     }

echo "</table>";     
mysql_close();

}
```

How can i save the Clients that have been ticked to receive a message after the user clicks the send button in the bootom right of the website in an array list. "I just want to save the primary key in an array list nothing else"

Can anyone please guide me?
Thanks in Regards

Comment: `<input type=checkbox name=checkbox[] value=$record['ID'] />` try this... On Server side you can get checked values using `$_POST['checkbox']`... Also input tag is not properly closed...

Comment: Don't use the deprecated mysql_ functions since they expose you to sql injection

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['checkbox']))
{
    foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $key => $value)
    {
        $receivemsg[] = $key;
    }
}
```

After this, you'll have an array (`$receivemsg`) containing `ID`s which have the checkbox ticked.

**Update: A sample array**
Below is a sample `var_dump()` of the array from 3 checkboxes. Only checkbox 2 and 3 is checked in this sample.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
  [1]=>
  int(3)
}
```

Comment: I try you suggestion it looks that it works only on the first checkboz though, its only checking if the first check box is isset

Comment: @user3397260 The first `if` statement only checks if _any_ checkbox is ticked. Without this, it will give you an error if you submit without ticking any checkbox. What is the result you get from the `$receivemsg`? Please try and check the result of your `var_dump($receivemsg)`. I've tested this solution and it returns an array of IDs for me. I've updated the answer with a sample output. Is that the expected outcome you wish?

Answer (score -1):

To save the Recieve Message value create some field in your Database Table with your desired name, if the client checks the `Recieve Message` Checkbox set it to `1` else set it to `0`. While fetching the data from Database check if the the value of that attribute is `1` then `echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked>." </td>";` else only `echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox'>." </td>";`. Let's say your attribute name is `rec_msg`
then do something like this:

```
if($record['rec_msg'] == '1') echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked>." </td>";
else echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox'>." </td>";
```

then your `while` loop will look like this

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($clients)){
  echo "<form action=pushnotification.php method=post>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$record['ID']." </td>";
  echo "<td>".$record['Name']." </td>";
  echo "<td>".$record['SurName']." </td>";
  if($record['rec_msg'] == '1') echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked>." </td>";
  else echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox'>." </td>";  
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</form>";
}
```